# async.each doesn't break after callback(error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I want to break out the loop after error encounterred.

```
var async = require('async');  

var objs = [{name:'A'}, {name:'B'}, {name:'C'}];  

function doSomething(obj, cb)  
{  
  console.log("Processing" + obj.name);  
  cb();  
}  
async.each(objs, function(obj, callback) {  
  doSomething(obj, function(){  
      callback("It's a err.");  
  });  
}, function(err){
    if(err)
     console.log("err is:" + err);  
});
```

I suppose it break out after the first iteration. However it outputs:

```
ProcessingA
err is:It's a err.
ProcessingB
ProcessingC
```

Shouldn't async.each stop the iteration after callback(err) is called? If not, why does it only invoke once? I can't see the idea behind this.  It just ignores other possible errors after the very first one?

It's indicated in the [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) that:

> ```
>   // One of the iterations produced an error.
>    // All processing will now stop.
> ```

Comment: `each` starts all tasks parallelly, you need to use `eachSeries`

Comment: yep,but the optional callback still can't be used for error handling in `each` since it invokes once only, even  though __A callback which is called when all iteratee functions have finished, or an error occurs. Invoked with (err)__  is documented. Looks like I have to  insert my own callback for the parallel case. Thanks.